# C# data to Java

Tags: java, c#

I want to check if a Windows Workstation is logged on or off. I've found a solution in **C#**:

```
public class CheckForWorkstationLocking : IDisposable
{
    private SessionSwitchEventHandler sseh;
    void SysEventsCheck(object sender, SessionSwitchEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.Reason)
        {
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionLock: Console.WriteLine("Lock Encountered"); break;
            case SessionSwitchReason.SessionUnlock: Console.WriteLine("UnLock Encountered"); break;
        }
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        sseh = new SessionSwitchEventHandler(SysEventsCheck);
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch += sseh;
    }


    #region IDisposable Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        SystemEvents.SessionSwitch -= sseh;
    }

    #endregion
}
```

but at the end I'm going to need this **boolean** in my `Java Program`.

I already tried the following:
I started both programs and **C#** writes into a file from where I can check all few seconds if the data has changed or not from **java** (don't need to say that this solution is just slow and insufficient)

Another solution would be :
**Java** starts the **C#** .exe which waits until **Java** connects to it through sockets and they share the data over the open connection.

Is there a better way to solve this with less effort than with this **socket** interface solution?

Comment: I would reverse engineer what C# is doing there, and implement it in Java. (Though I don't think that the API that provides you the information is only available for C#.)

Comment: What about running the C# exe with `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` class and check the return value or read the `OutputStream` ? This will avoid socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to go to any complicated lengths to get this done.  It can be quite simple.

Save the boolean into a file in C#, then have a file watcher watching the directory in Java.  If there is a change it can read the file in Java and find the value of the boolean.  Such a solution would not be expensive and eat up a lot of CPU cycles, like a solution where you had a while loop that checked the file would be.

The beginnings of the Java code can be as simple as

```
import static java.nio.file.StandardWatchEventKinds.*;

Path dir = ...;
try {
    WatchKey key = dir.register(watcher,
                           ENTRY_CREATE,
                           ENTRY_DELETE,
                           ENTRY_MODIFY);
} catch (IOException x) {
    System.err.println(x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of possible solutions to this issue. My personal preference would be to use a message queue to post messages between the applications. (http://zeromq.org/ is light and would be my recommendation)

The advantage of this approach is the two applications are decoupled and and its not relying on   the filesystem which is notoriously prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

To call a function that is written in C# (or any .NET library function) from Java, you can use JNI.

However, all JNI will do is get you to C/C++. You will need to write a simple managed C++ object that can forward request from the unmanaged side to the .NET library.

[Example Here](http://s0ft1.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/p2-calling-c-from-java/)